# How to get an element's left/top attribute in RAW JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I created a codePen here (http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pwoEJ)

> document.querySelector('#box').style.left

This line of code doesn't seem return the right value? It gives me "" empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle):

```
document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('#box')).left
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this,http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjfGu

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById('box'),null).getPropertyValue('left');
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends how cross-browser you want your code to be.

getComputedStyle is not available in IE8- (not sure if it works on IE9 either)

Also, the style might have been already set programmatically, in which case you will find the value inside the `element.style` object.

Finally, while getComputedStyle accepts CSS-like identifiers (e.g. `z-index`), the other ways of accessing style elements use camelized names (e.g. `zIndex`).

In the end, a more general solution is far from trivial:

```
getStyle = function getStyle (el, property) 
{
    var style;
    if(document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle)
    {
       style = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el, "")
              .getPropertyValue (property);
    if (style) return style;
    }
    property = Camelize (property); // this is for older IE versions
    if (el.currentStyle) style = el.currentStyle[property];

    return style || el.style[property]
}

function Camelize (string)
{
    var oStringList = string.split('-');
    if (oStringList.length == 1) return oStringList[0];

    var camelizedString = string.indexOf('-') == 0
        ? oStringList[0].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + oStringList[0].substring(1)
        : oStringList[0];

    for (var i = 1, len = oStringList.length; i < len; i++)
    {
        var s = oStringList[i];
        camelizedString += s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1);
    }
    return camelizedString;
}
```

*(this code adapted for readability from Bernard Sumption's excellent Animator.js library)*